# Understanding predicates in alloy

Tags: alloy

Can someone please help me understand predicates using the following example:

```
sig Light{}
sig LightState { color: Light -> one Color}
sig Junction {lights: set Light}
fun redLigths(s:LightState) : set Light{ s.color.Red}
pred mostlyRed(s:LightState, j:Junction){
    lone j.lights - redLigths(s)
}
```

I have the below questions about the above code:

1) What happens if the above predicate is true?

2) What happends if it is false?

3) Can someone show me a bit of alloy code that uses the above code and clarifies the meaning of predicates through the code.

I am just trying to understand how do we use the above predicate.

Comment: Is this homework? Not going to withhold information either way, just interested in knowing :)

Comment: No. I am trying to pick up alloy in a short amount of time. Thus, thought using Stack overflow was a good idea since their website says that SO is the best place to ask alloy related info

Comment: Got called by boss, sorry for the delay, I have an answer in the making :) but it will take a while.

Comment: Great. I am waiting. Posted another simple question about set. Pls help. sig A{ rel : set B }. Does set refer to 0 or more. Or does it refer to 1 or more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing "happens" until you place a call to a predicate or a function in a command to find an example or counterexample.

Comment: What happens if there is no such instance that satisfies the predicate. Also, can you give me some runnable alloy code using the above example that i can play with so that i can try different things.

Comment: In the definition for mostlyRed, does set refer to ( 0 or more) OR does it refer to (1 or more)?

Answer (score 3):

First, use the right terminology, nothing 'happens' when a predicate is true; it's the more like the other way around, an instance (an allocation of atoms to sets) satisfies (or doesn't) some condition, making the predicate true (or false).

Also, your model is incomplete, because there is no `sig` declaration for `Color` (which should include an attribute called `Red`).

I assume you want to model a world with crossroads containing traffic lights, if so I would use the following model:

```
abstract sig Color {}

one sig Red,Yellow,Green extends Color {}

sig Light {
    color: Color
}

sig Junction {
    lights : set Light
}

// This is just for realism, make sure each light belongs to exactly one junction
fact {
    Light = Junction.lights
    no x,y:Junction | x!=y and some x.lights & y.lights
}

fun count[j:Junction, c:Color] : Int { 
    #{x:Light | x in j.lights and x.color=c}
}

pred mostly[j:Junction, c:Color] {
    no cc:Color | cc!=c and count[j,cc]>=count[j,c]
}

run{
    some j:Junction | mostly[j,Red]
} for 10 Light, 2 Junction, 10 int
```

Looking at the above, i'm using the # operator to count the number of atoms in a set, and I'm specifying a bitwidth of 10 to integers just so that I don't stumble into an overflow when using the # operator for large sets.

When you execute this, you will get an instance with at least one junction that has mostly red lights, it will be marked as `$j` in the visualizer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
sig Light{}
sig LightState { color: Light -> one Color}
sig Junction {lights: set Light}
fun redLigths(s:LightState) : set Light{ s.color.Red}
pred mostlyRed(s:LightState, j:Junction){
lone j.lights - redLigths(s)
}
```

What the predicate simply means in the example you gave is;

The difference between the set A, in this case the relation (j.lights) and another set say B, returned from the function redligths, of which the Predicate will always constraint the constraint analyser to return only red light when you run the Predicate "mostlyRed".

And note that the multiplicity "**lone**" you added to the predicate's body only evaluate after the difference between the set A and B (as I assumed) has been evaluated, to make sure that **at most one atom of red** is returned. I hope my explanation was helpful. I will welcome positive criticism. Thanks